# Website downloads IE components again after changing IP address

Tags: activex, internet-explorer-6

We are running HP Quality Center 10.
This can only be run in Internet Explorer as it relies on ActiveX.
When logging into this web based app for the first time, various components download and install.

- Windows Installer 3.0 or later
- CAPICOM 2.1.0.2   Microsoft .NET
- Framework 3.5 SP1   Microsoft Visual
- C++ 2005 SP1 library

Also a QC Client MSI downloads and installs.
Subsequently logging in on the same machine obviously does not re-download and re-install.

This works fine, however we are testing migrating our Quality Center server to a different IP address.
We have discovered that when changing the IP address, IE will forcibly re-download and re-install all of these client side components.  This happens even though they are definitely already installed on the client machine.
IE seems to register what is installed against a particular IP address.
This causes a big problem for us since our users do not have sufficient privileges on their machines to allow a re-install.

Is there any registry change that we could do to re-map the existing installation to the new IP address?
Is there any way we could prevent IE from re-downloading this stuff?
Can anyone help me at all?

Our organisation runs Internet Explorer 6 (this will not be able to be changed).

Comment: You're stuck with an obsolete product that is end of life. I don't think you'll be able to change it, and you may just have to bite the bullet, unless you map the IP to a hostname, and then map the new IP to the same host. While you'll have to download everything again, at least it'll be linked to a host and not an IP. Just a thought.

Comment: Are you accessing the app by IP address? Perhaps Quality Center is setting a cookie to remember if the items have been installed. Investigate if you can copy cookies saved for the old IP address to the new IP address. As Randolph said, a better long term solution may be to map an appropriate hostname for the app.